# Get day of the week in month (2nd Tuesday, etc.)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need an algorithm for calculating the number of the day of the week in the month. Like 1st Friday of the month, 3rd Monday of the month, etc.)

Any ideas are appreciated.

Here is the final result:

```
declare @dt date =  GetDate()

declare @DayOfWeek tinyint = datepart(weekday,@dt)
declare @DayOfMonth smallint = day(@dt)
declare @FirstDayOfMonth date = dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@dt),0)
declare @DayOfWeekInMonth tinyint = @DayOfMonth / 7 + 1 -
        (case when day(@FirstDayOfMonth) > day(@dt) then 1 else 0 end)
declare @Suffix varchar(2) = 
        case 
            when @DayOfWeekInMonth = 1 then 'st'
            when @DayOfWeekInMonth = 2 then 'nd'
            when @DayOfWeekInMonth = 3 then 'rd'
            when @DayOfWeekInMonth > 3 then 'th'
        end

select 
    cast(@DayOfWeekInMonth as varchar(2)) 
    + @Suffix 
    + ' ' 
    + datename(weekday,@Dt) 
    + ' of ' 
    + datename(month,@dt) 
    + ', ' 
    + datename(year,@Dt)
```

PS: And if you can think of a better way to state the problem, please do.

Comment: why would you do this in sql? What have you tried so far? What has worked for you and what has not?

Comment: That it be in SQL is a requirement I can't change. It needs to be part of a stored proc that adds rows to a date dimension table and is to be run by SQL Server Agent annually to populate the next year.

Comment: Oh, and I'm working on it. Just thought someone else would want in on the fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followint code will give you `1st Wednesday of April 2014` for today:

```
SELECT cast((DATEPART(d, GETDATE() - 1) / 7) + 1 as varchar(12)) 
+ 'st ' + DATENAME(WEEKDAY, getdate()) + ' of ' +
DATENAME(month, getdate()) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, getdate());
```

For any date use the code below. It gives `5th Tuesday of April 2014` for `@mydate = '2014-04-29'` in the example:

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME;
SET @mydate = '2014-04-29';

SELECT 
case
    when DATEPART(d, @mydate) = 1 then  cast((DATEPART(d, @mydate ) / 7) + 1 as varchar(12)) 
    else cast((DATEPART(d, @mydate - 1) / 7) + 1 as varchar(12)) 
end
+ 
case
    when  (DATEPART(d, @mydate - 1) / 7) + 1  = 1 then  'st '
    when  (DATEPART(d, @mydate - 1) / 7) + 1  = 2 then  'nd '  
    when  (DATEPART(d, @mydate - 1) / 7) + 1  = 3 then  'rd '   
    else 'th '
end
+ DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @mydate) + ' of ' +
DATENAME(month, @mydate) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, @mydate) as [Long Date Name]
```

Comment: What about 2nd, 3rd , 4th like appends?

Comment: It works but fails for this value `SET @mydate = getdate()  -1;`

Comment: Slight adjustment needed, but you got the credit. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okeeeey my tuuuurn ,

Please rate my answer Metaphor hhh, Here's the cooode :

```
declare  @v_month nvarchar(2) = '04'
        ,@v_annee nvarchar(4) = '2014'

declare @v_date date = convert(date,@v_annee+'-'+@v_month+'-01')
declare @v_date_2 date = dateadd(M,1,@v_date)

if OBJECT_ID('temp') is not null
    drop table temp

create table temp(_date date, _DayOfMonth nvarchar(20), _order int)

while (@v_date<@v_date_2)
begin
    set @v_date =@v_date;
    WITH _DayOfWeek AS (
            SELECT 1 id, 'monday' Name UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 id, 'tuesday' Name UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 id, 'wednesday' Name UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 id, 'thursday' Name UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 id, 'friday' Name UNION ALL
            SELECT 6 id, 'saturday' Name UNION ALL
            SELECT 7 id, 'sunday' Name)
    insert into temp(_date,_DayOfMonth)
     SELECT
         @v_date
        ,(select Name from _DayOfWeek where id = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@v_date))

    SET @v_date = DATEADD(DAY,1,@v_date)

END

UPDATE tmp1
    SET _order = _order_2
FROM temp tmp1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY _DayOfMonth ORDER BY _date ASC) AS     _order_2 FROM temp) tmp2
        ON tmp1._date = tmp2._date

SELECT * FROM temp

SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE _DayOfMonth = 'thursday'
AND _order = 3
```

I hope this will help you :)
Good Luck

Comment: A bit over complicated for my taste. The solution can be stated much simpler. +1 for trying.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's what I came up with, I'll +1 everyone who answered anyway:

```
declare @dt date =  GetDate()

declare @DayOfWeek tinyint = datepart(weekday,@dt)
declare @DayOfMonth smallint = day(@dt)
declare @FirstDayOfMonth date = dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@dt),0)
declare @DayOfWeekInMonth tinyint = 
    @DayOfMonth / 7 + 1 
    - (case when day(@FirstDayOfMonth) > day(@dt) then 1 else 0 end)
declare @Suffix varchar(2) = 
        case 
            when @DayOfWeekInMonth = 1 then 'st'
            when @DayOfWeekInMonth = 2 then 'nd'
            when @DayOfWeekInMonth = 3 then 'rd'
            when @DayOfWeekInMonth > 3 then 'th'
        end

select 
    cast(@DayOfWeekInMonth as varchar(2)) 
    + @Suffix 
    + ' ' 
    + datename(weekday,@Dt) 
    + ' of ' 
    + datename(month,@dt) 
    + ', ' 
    + datename(year,@Dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @dt date = getdate()

declare @DayOfMonth smallint = datepart(d, @dt)

declare @Suffix varchar(2) = 
    case
        when floor((@DayOfMonth - 1) / 7.0) = 0 then 'st' -- implies there were no such days previously in the month
        when floor((@DayOfMonth - 1) / 7.0) = 1 then 'nd'
        when floor((@DayOfMonth - 1) / 7.0) = 2 then 'rd'
        else 'th'
    end 

select cast(floor((@DayOfMonth - 1) / 7.0) + 1 as varchar(1)) + @Suffix + 
' ' + datename(weekday, @dt) + ' of ' + datename(month, @dt) + 
', ' + datename(year, @dt)
```

Comment: You do this with floating point? What's this a shot in the dark?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME
SET @dt = DATEADD(d, 6, GETDATE())

SELECT @dt, 
    CAST((DAY(@dt) / 7) + CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @dt) >= DATEPART(weekday, CAST(MONTH(@dt) AS NVARCHAR) + '/01/' + CAST(YEAR(@dt) AS NVARCHAR)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NVARCHAR)
  + '' + CASE (DAY(@dt) / 7) + CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @dt) >= DATEPART(weekday, CAST(MONTH(@dt) AS NVARCHAR) + '/01/' + CAST(YEAR(@dt) AS NVARCHAR)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            WHEN 1 THEN N'st'
            WHEN 2 THEN N'nd'
            WHEN 3 THEN N'rd'
            ELSE N'th'
         END
  + ' ' + DATENAME(dw, @dt)
  + ' of ' + DATENAME(M, @dt)
  + ', ' + CAST(YEAR(@dt) AS NVARCHAR)
```

Result is a single SELECT (provided the assignment of @dt happened earlier) but is, essentially, the same logic as yours.

Comment: And Binaya's -- redundancy at its best.

Answer (score 0):

This following code will give you `DATE` for any day of the week in any month or year that you specify. All the variables that I have are to reduce repeating logic to improve code speed.

This code gives you date for `1st Monday in February in 2013`

```
DECLARE @DayNumber INT = 1
    ,@DayWeekNumber INT = 2
    ,@MonthNumber INT = 2
    ,@YearNumber INT = 2013
    ,@FoM DATE
    ,@FoMWD INT;

SET @FoM    = DATEFROMPARTS(@YearNumber,@MonthNumber,1)
SET @fomwd  = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @FoM);

SELECT CASE WHEN @fomwd = @DayWeekNumber THEN DATEADD(WEEK, @DayNumber - 1, @FoM)
            WHEN @fomwd < @DayWeekNumber THEN DATEADD(DAY, @DayWeekNumber - @fomwd, DATEADD(WEEK, @DayNumber - 1, @FoM))
            WHEN @fomwd > @DayWeekNumber THEN DATEADD(DAY, @DayWeekNumber - @fomwd, DATEADD(WEEK, @DayNumber, @FoM))
        END AS DateOfDay;
```

Comment: Wow, man. You sure like to type! All I really need is DayOfMonth / 7 +  1 and adjust it for when the day of the week at the start of the month is after the current day of the week.

Comment: Why would you use seven IFs to get the day of the week number when you can get that with one datepart? And all those parameters? Just, wow...

Comment: 7 `IF` statements are in case if you want to use name of the day instead of number. Also I'm not doing it based on current day but based on passed in parameter, this is done so it can be stored proc or function that can return `DATE` datatype based on anything you want not just what today is.

Comment: All you need for a passed parameter is a single date. Anything needed can be gotten from that. The way I implemented it, it's a function that takes a date and returns the DayOfWeekInMonth.

Comment: @Metaphor than tell me what is `4 Thursday in November of 1997` you can't because you rely on the date provided to you to figure out what it is. Mine is done from the opposite side to give you date base on request.

Comment: Ok, maybe someone can use this.